# Запятая перед *сколько* ставится всегда?

Tags: пунктуация

> Ночь была настолько тёмная, что, *сколько* я ни старалась рассмотреть, что творилось во дворе, не могла этого сделать.

Почему перед *сколько* ставится запятая? Ведь нет второй части для союза *сколько*. Если бы была вторая часть в виде *то* (...,***то*** не могла этого сделать), тогда запятая перед *сколько* была бы оправдана.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Союз "сколько" вообще не требует второй "части". Вы его, возможно, с "если" смешали.

Сочетание "сколько ни... , (но) ...] является местоименно-союзным сочетанием, присоединяющим придаточное уступительное. Как и всякое придаточное, оно требует обособления запятыми.
http://syntax.academic.ru/260/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5

Могут быть другие трактовки грамматики ("разбора"), но все равно нужно обособление.

Answer (score 2):

> Почему перед *сколько* ставится запятая? Ведь нет второй части для
>   союза *сколько*. Если бы была вторая часть в виде *то (...,**то** не
>   могла этого сделать)*, тогда запятая перед сколько была бы оправдана.

См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134 :

> **§ 123.** В сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными частями, а также в сложном предложении с сочинением и подчинением
>   могут оказаться рядом два союза (или союз и союзное слово): два
>   подчинительных союза (или подчинительный союз и союзное слово),
>   сочинительный и подчинительный союз (или сочинительный союз и союзное
>   слово). Союзы разделяются или не разделяются запятой в зависимости от
>   следующих условий.
>
> 1. **Запятая** на стыке союзов **ставится**, если после первого союза следует **одиночный союз** в придаточной части...
> 2. Если после первого союза следует **двойной союз**, то **запятая** на стыке союзов **не ставится**. Это случается, когда подчинительный
>      союз имеет в главной части предложения слово ***то***...